# Inbox zero for IMAP

Tags: email, time-management, productivity, email-client, imap

I am searching an application to help me to get inbox zero for my mails.

Wanted features:

- Re-submission of mails should be easy: +*N* days, +*N* weeks
- Connect to IMAP mail server (I use Dovecot)
- Should be usable from Ubuntu PC

Optional:

- Open source
- Android support
- Mail user agent: it would be nice if I could reply via this tool

#### What I mean with inbox zero

I don't want to look at *N* mails at once (reading *N* subjects). I want to look at exactly one email. Then I can decide:

- do this today
- delete this
- do resubmission in *N* days or *N* weeks

After the decision was made the next mail gets shown.